# how can I display the data contained in a JSON file in my web page using : (vuejs) (springboot)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying to display data from a JSON file on a web page. I'm using a Spring Boot backend to send the streaming data to vue Js which displays it in an array.

**My Spring Boot code :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getData() throws IOException {
    Path filePath = Paths.get("My_Data.json");
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(filePath);
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    };
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**My vuejs code :**

```
   AffichageData() {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/apii/getData')
    .then((response) => {
      this.items = response.data
      console.log('la reponse est', response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

To display my data  :

```
<table class="content-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data1</th>
      <th>Data2</th>
      <th>Data3</th>
      <th>Data4</th>
      <th>Data5</th>
      <th>Data6</th>
      <th>More</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.Data1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Data2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Data3 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Data4 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Data5 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.Data6 }}</td>
      <td>
        <button id="MoreInfo" v-on:click="afficher(item)"><a href="/Detail">...</a></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It works but for files that are not very big. I have files that are bigger than 210 MB and for these files the display freezes.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1087) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
> .......
>
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:228) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:740) ~[?:?]
> ......

If anyone has a solution of how I can display and solve this problem? and how I can display the data on multiple pages instead of all displaying on one ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vue or or the front-end. Your Java process is out of memory.

Comment: yes this message is for the backend. but in the frontend too i have problems in case the backend has no problem the frontend stops when it tries to display a lot of data and the web page flatlines completely.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual list scroll lib might help with this, you will have to find something suitable for your needs. Here is a link to the general concept (this one demos using react but you are looking for a similar thing):

https://blog.logrocket.com/virtual-scrolling-core-principles-and-basic-implementation-in-react/

---

If the amount of data is simply too much to load in the first place, I would introduce pagination and use the page position to read a and return a limited range of the original source.

Perhaps parse the entire file and hold it in memory as a set of records you can page. Try reading up on large data iteration patterns like this:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-iterate-large-result-sets

Comment: thank you it gives me clues for the next step. i'll see.